# How to set up own CDN with subdomain on Typo3 v8?

Tags: typo3, subdomain, cdn, typo3-8.x

As [Content Replacer (ja_replacer)](https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/ja_replacer/) is not supported by Typo3 v8 is there any other way to replace url strings in Typo3 v8 and setup own CDN Service?

To make it more clear, in Typo3 v4.5-6.1 it would look like that:

```
config.tx_ja_replacer {
  search {
    1="typo3temp/
    2="fileadmin/
    3="typo3conf/
  }
  replace {
    1="https://cdn.domain.de/typo3temp/
    2="https://cdn.domain.de/fileadmin/
    3="https://cdn.domain.de/typo3conf/
  }
}
```

But this extension is not supported anymore.

Thanks in advance!

---- EDIT 1 ----

If someone is still interested in 'ja_replacer', this is a Typo3 v7 & v8 Fork:
[ja_replace for Typo3 v7-8](https://github.com/PHORAX/ja-replacer)

With this I managed it to work but encountered CORS problems even if fonts where set to wildcard origins

---- EDIT 2 ----

Testes this (by Mario Naether) but this also did not worked (even with page.stdWrap.replacement)

```
page.stdWrap.replacement {
  10.search = #"fileadmin\/#
  10.replace = "https://cdn.domain.de/fileadmin/
  10.useRegExp = 1
  11.search = #"typo3temp\/#
  11.replace = "https://cdn.domain.de/typo3temp/
  11.useRegExp = 1
  12.search = #"typo3conf\/#
  12.replace = "https://cdn.domain.de/typo3conf/
  12.useRegExp = 1
}
```

---- EDIT 3 ----

Finaly I found a solution which satisfies me. (if I'm logged in)
I posted it here as answer.

**This is actually working.. but not if I'm not logged in...** 
So now I have to manage it to work even if I load the Website without beeing logged in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Soooo after some days of research I found a good solution which is working with Typo3 v7.6.0 - v8.99.99

Install [ja-replacer](https://github.com/PHORAX/ja-replacer/) (by PHORAX)

and add this Code to your TypoScript

```
#CDN über Sub-Domain 'CDN.DOMAIN.de'
config.tx_ja_replacer{
  search {
    10="/typo3temp/
    11="typo3temp/
    12="/fileadmin/
    13="fileadmin/
    14="/typo3conf/
    15="typo3conf/
  }

  replace {
    10="https://CDN.DOMAIN.de/typo3temp/
    11="https://CDN.DOMAIN.de/typo3temp/
    12="https://CDN.DOMAIN.de/fileadmin/
    13="https://CDN.DOMAIN.de/fileadmin/
    14="https://CDN.DOMAIN.de/typo3conf/
    15="https://CDN.DOMAIN.de/typo3conf/
  }
}

#Domain-replace Setup für CDN
[globalString = ENV:HTTP_HOST = WWW.DOMAIN.de]
  page.config.baseURL = https://WWW.DOMAIN.de/
  config.tx_ja_replacer.replace < tx_ja_replacer
[global]
```

1.) Now replace every "**cdn.domain.de**" with your own CDN-Subdomain or CDN-Domain

2.) replace every "**www.domain.de**" to your Domain.

2b) if necessary change the value of "**page.config.baseURL**" to just http and not https if your not using https

---- EDIT 1 ----

Somehow this is just working fine as long as I'm logged in.
When I load my Typo3 Website without beeing logged in it does not replace anything.

Answer (score 1):

You can used the stdWrap function from TYPO3. This works with all TYPO3 versions >= 6.2.

```
page.stdWrap.replacement {
    10.search = #"fileadmin\/_processed_\/#
    10.replace = "https://cdn.mydoamin.de/fileadmin/_processed_/
    10.useRegExp = 1
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. I modified your code a bit (as you can see in my mainpost) but it did not help. Somehow every picture-link stays /fileadmin/... and is not cdn.domain.de/fileadmin/...
Is there something I have done wrong?

Comment: @Blabla Sorry, I posted a wrong config. You must use page.stdWarp.replacement (https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/7.6/Functions/Replacement/)

Comment: Thanks for correcting this. I updated my TypoScript Code but even now it does not work. This is so frustrating.
Btw: I found a solution which works fine when I'm logged in. May you know why it is not working in the frontend (when I open my site without beeing logged in)?

Comment: This works just the TYPO3 Cache is disabled if you logged in! I hadn't test this TS with TYPO3 v8. Only with v6 and v7. You can try to set "useRegExp = 0" and remove '#' in search pattern.

Answer (score 0):

TYPO3 extension **replacecontent** from Michiel Roos, MaxServ has nearly the same functionality. https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/replacecontent/
Current version is still only compatible with TYPO3 7.6, but it can easily been made TYPO3 8 compatible, while fork on github https://github.com/MaxServ/t3ext-replacecontent and improve existing code.

Comment: Thank you! Its still **not** working as now my links are looking like this: https://www.domain.de/%7B$config.tx_replacecontent.schema%7D%7B$config.tx_replacecontent.host%7D/fileadmin/introduction/images/Logo-inverted.svg